# How can I hover my TextButtons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I created three textbuttons in Flutter and now I want to hover their color from their default color to pink color. In the moment that my mouse is on the button, the button should change it's color to pink. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
Container(
          color: Colors.grey[900],
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[600])),
                child: const Text(
                  'Registrieren',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20,),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 12,
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[600])),
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20,),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 12,
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[600])),
                child: const Text(
                  'Kontakt',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20,),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: use onHover() param of TextButton & maintain 3 booleans outside build. Inside onHover do setState & update the values of boolean to onHover boolean

Comment: Can you show me how to put in my code please? @Prashant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter web - On hover how to change Flatbutton TEXT color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371978/flutter-web-on-hover-how-to-change-flatbutton-text-color)

Answer (score 1):

For the `textButton` we can use `foregroundColor` property of `ButtonStyle`.

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
  foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered))
      return Colors.pink;
    return Colors.yellow; // null throus error in flutter 2.2+.
    }
  ),
),
  onPressed: () { },
  child: Text('TextButton with custom overlay colors'),
)
```

Comment: I did it but it returns nothing.  @Sabahat

Answer (score 0):

You need 'FocusableActionDetector'

```
FocusableActionDetector(
    actions: _actionMap,
    shortcuts: _shortcutMap,
    onShowHoverHighlight: _handleHoveHighlight,
    child:  // your button 

 
    ),
  ),




  bool _hovering = false;

  void _handleHoveHighlight(bool value) {
     setState(() {
        _hovering = value;
     });
   }
```

check here for more details

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusableActionDetector-class.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't resolved the issue, or somebody else stumbles upon it...

[Sabahat Hussain Qureshi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73658698) solution was correct, but maybe you were looking for something else... Anyway, you can achieve it by setting global theme like this:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    // HERE
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.redAccent),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
              return Colors.black;
            }
            return null; // defer to the defaults
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

or per instance:

```
return TextButton(
  // OR HERE
  style: const ButtonStyle(/* ... */),
  // ...
);
```

[image: Example]